# How to make a proper move in/out animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

In `onViewCreate` I set the view behind the screen:

```
holderMenus.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        if (holderMenus != null) {
          if (DeviceType.INSTANCE.tablet) {
            holderMenus.animate().translationY(-holderMenus.getHeight());
          } else {
            holderMenus.animate().translationY(holderMenus.getHeight());
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Then, when I want to move the view in:

```
  holderMenus.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(300);
```

That works well; the view slides in. Next I want to move the view off the screen:

```
 if (DeviceType.INSTANCE.tablet) {
     holderMenus.animate().translationY(-holderMenus.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
 } else {
     holderMenus.animate().translationY(holderMenus.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
 }
```

But instead of sliding, the view disappears, as if I had set the property to `.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

How can I make it slide instead?

Comment: At what point of the lifecycle do you execute the animation ? Have you tried to call it on a button click for example ?

Comment: @koperko initially it is run, when view created (works well), then I pres button to slide it in ( works well), then i press button to hide it (instead of slide out it just diassapers, like visibility is changed to gone)

Comment: try to add .start()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a custom action button that slides from below the screen and slides back under the screen when listview is scrolled.

Hides:

```
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500);
        anim.setDuration(300l);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        layout.startAnimation(anim); //layout is the layout with the button

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                layout.clearAnimation();
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 300l);
```

Shows:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 500, 0);
                        anim.setDuration(300l);
                        anim.setFillAfter(true);
                        layout.startAnimation(anim);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 500l);
```

Comment: Use anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() { instead of postDelayed

Answer (score 0):

I guess that slide out animation is not starting from the point that you think it is. It probably "animates" in the same position off the screen.

You might want to try ObjectAnimator, where you can specify both starting and ending points for your animation using `ofFloat` method for example.